# magento search not showing single product on manufactuer list page

Tags: magento

Magneto search not showing single product on manufacturer list page,
it redirecting product on product page.

I don't want to redirect it, i am notable to find ta redirect code.
I am using search landing page for show listing of brand vise product

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more detail? And show us some code? Is you manufacturer list page a category or created by some extension?

Comment: it is by default by magento, i just add in search landing page, 'manufacturer/xyzbrand' it show all product by xyzbrand